# Error when trying to install packages using Pear

Tags: php, pear, phing, ubuntu-14.04

I have been trying unsuccessfully to install some pear packages for hours. I first tried to install phing to no avail then I tried installing it with the `-alldeps` flag still to no hope. I then tried installing phpUnit but I got the same error I got while trying to install phing. I am at the end of my rope. Here are the pastes [1st trial](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7294327/) and [2nd trial with `-alldeps flag`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7294364/). Any help availed will be appreciated.

Comment: That behavior (bug) is reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/1310552

Comment: I'm the one who reported the bug

Comment: Thanks for posting bug. It might help to paste the command you used and keep the pastebin. In this way, others (like me) can see at a glance that this question applies to me as well, or not.

Comment: but there already is a link to my pastes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to add the channel pear.phing.info

```
pear channel-discover pear.phing.info
```

See also

http://www.phing.info/docs/stable/webhelp/ch03s03.html

Comment: as can be seen from my question there are two pastes and that command did not help.